# constructor issue in nestjs framework

Tags: puppeteer, nestjs

I'm learning NestJs and puppeteer.

I tried web crawl and it worked well.

But because of launching and closing headless browser, it takes a lot of response time.

I think it's better launching browser just one time than every launching and closing.

But i don't know how i use constructor in NestJS. It looks different from Vanila javascript.

```
async crawlData() {
        const browser = await launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("https://ko.reactjs.org/");
        await page.screenshot({ path: "./Docs/ko-reactjs-homepage.png" });
        await browser.close();
}
```

Please understand that i'm not native english speaker.

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by not knowing how to use the constructor? NestJS is a framework for NodeJS, mostly used by typescript users, but JavaScript can work too. A class in Typescript works pretty much the same in JS, so to use the constructor it would be `new ClassName(parametersToPass)` to create a new class instance.

Comment: I want to declare browser just one time. But in NestJS, constructor is used to inject module dependency. What I'm trying to implement is declare headless browser asynchronous in constructor. It doesn't work properly. I think there is something to know about NestJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) for the browser so it can be opened once and don't need to open it again. Something along the lines of

```js
{
  provide: 'PUPPETEER_INSTANCE',
  useFactory: async () => await launch()
}
```

And now in a constructor in a service that belongs to same module you can do `@Inject('PUPPETEER_INSTANCE') private readonly puppeteer)`

Comment: That works for me. Thanks :)..
But i'm still confusing about custom provider.
Will the above code be executed before the Provider is created?